# Equivalent of split_function() in HIVE

Tags: hive, bigdata, etl, hiveql, impala

As per my project requirement I have come up with one complex logic which has 'a small section' as following:

```
    'regexp_extract(split_part(vw_cart.order_detail,':',2), '[0-9]+', 0)'
```

It works like a charm in IMPALA but fails in HIVE.

I am working on to find something similar to 'SPLIT_PART' for HIVE execution of my Code.

Any guidance will be  helpful.

Comment: does `split` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive `split()` function returns array and array elements are numbered started from 0.

In Impala `split_part(vw_cart.order_detail,':',2)` - returns second element from delimited string, numbered from 1

So, in Hive it will be:

```
regexp_extract(split(vw_cart.order_detail,':')[1], '[0-9]+', 0)
```

Comment: So simple, yet so effective. Thanks.